# Choosing between Stream and Collections API

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following example that prints the maximum element in a `List` :

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,4,3,9,7,4,8);           
list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

The same objective can also be achieved using the `Collections.max` method :

```
System.out.println(Collections.max(list));
```

The above code is not only shorter but also cleaner to read (in my opinion). There are similar examples that come to mind such as the use of `binarySearch` vs `filter` used in conjunction with `findAny`.

I understand that  `Stream` can be an infinite pipeline as opposed to a `Collection` that is limited by the memory available to the JVM. This would be my criteria for deciding whether to use a `Stream` or the `Collections` API. Are there any other reasons for choosing `Stream` over the `Collections` API (such as performance). More generally, is this the only reason to chose `Stream` over older API that can do the job in a cleaner and shorter way?

Comment: Are you asking only about this specific method?

Comment: If your only interest is in getting the `max` value from the list, the `Collections` method is the way to go.

Comment: Also, the `Optional` vs `NoSuchElementException` behavior.

Comment: If you had an `IntStream` instead of a `Stream<Integer>` it would be simpler: `ints.max().ifPresent(System.out::println);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am comparing `Collections` with the `Stream` API to limit the scope of the question. But even in the limited comparison, I can see that methods such as `binarySearch` are more readable than `list.stream().filter(i->i>0).findAny().ifPresent(System.out::println)`. I want to be sure that there is no real advantage (performance, maintainability, readability etc)  of using `Stream` over older APIs in such situations.

Comment: @assylias I don't think it would be that easy to use IntStream` to get the `max` in a `List<Integer>`? As I understand from an answer I was reading earlier that motivated this question, it would look like this : `IntStream.range(0,list.size()).boxed().max(Comparator.comparing(list::get)).ifPresent(System.out::println)` which looks like hell.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Does this mean that just like `Collections.max`, `Stream.max` will traverse the entire `Collection` to get the `max` element?

Comment: list.stream().mapToInt(s -> s).max().ifPresent(System.out::println);

Comment: @swinker Still ugly.

Comment: @ChetanKinger more like `list.stream().mapToInt(I -> i).max()` but what I meant is that it may be cleaner to work with primitives only (no `List<Integer>` as a starting point). If that's not an option then there is probably little reason to use a stream here... If you only need a Max then stream is probably overkill. When you start filtering and mapping it becomes a lot more useful...

Comment: @ChetanKinger True. If your elements are "only" integers you might be right, Collections.max is much more readable. But it only supports the natural ordering where you can use any Comparator for the Stream API.

Comment: I just found one more reason to use `Stream` over `Collections` API. Parallelism and multi-core architecture.

Comment: Be cautious: just using `parallel()` can often _massively slow down_ performance.  Don't use it unless you have actual numbers.

Comment: Stream is new, so some people are abusing it - just for practice/fun.

Comment: `Stream`s introduce a paradigm shift from plain old _imperative_ style to _functional_. With this in mind, I think the things mentioned in [Guava's functional explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) also apply to Java 8 lambdas (even if they're less verbose than using anonymous classes). Bottom line: imperative style (or using utility methods from e.g. `Collections`) should be the default. It's very easy to abuse functional idioms, but OTOH, they're super useful and fluent when used correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stream API is like a Swiss Army knife: it allows you to do quite complex operations by combining the tools effectively. On the other hand if you just need a screwdriver, probably the standalone screwdriver would be more convenient. Stream API includes many things (like `distinct`, `sorted`, primitive operations etc.) which otherwise would require you to write several lines and introduce intermediate variables/data structures and boring loops drawing the programmer attention from the actual algorithm. Sometimes using the Stream API can improve the performance even for sequential code. For example, consider some old API:

```
class Group {
    private Map<String, User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return new ArrayList<>(users.values());
    }
}
```

Here we want to return all the users of the group. The API designer decided to return a `List`. But it can be used outside in a various ways:

```
List<User> users = group.getUsers();
Collections.sort(users);
someOtherMethod(users.toArray(new User[users.size]));
```

Here it's sorted and converted to array to pass to some other method which happened to accept an array. In the other place `getUsers()` may be used like this:

```
List<User> users = group.getUsers();
for(User user : users) {
    if(user.getAge() < 18) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Underage user in selected group!");
    }
}
```

Here we just want to find the user matched some criteria. In both cases copying to intermediate `ArrayList` was actually unnecessary. When we move to Java 8, we can replace `getUsers()` method with `users()`:

```
public Stream<User> users() {
    return users.values().stream();
}
```

And modify the caller code. The first one:

```
someOtherMethod(group.users().sorted().toArray(User[]::new));
```

The second one:

```
if(group.users().anyMatch(user -> user.getAge() < 18)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Underage user in selected group!");
}
```

This way it's not only shorter, but may work faster as well, because we skip the intermediate copying.

The other conceptual point in Stream API is that any stream code written according to the guidelines can be parallelized simply by adding the `parallel()` step. Of course this will not always boost the performance, but it helps more often than I expected. Usually if the operation executed sequentially for [0.1ms or longer](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html), it can benefit from the parallelization. Anyways we haven't seen such simple way to do the parallel programming in Java before.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it always depends on the circumstances. Take you initial example:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,4,3,9,7,4,8);           
list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

If you want to do the *same* thing efficiently, you would use

```
IntStream.of(1,4,3,9,7,4,8).max().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

which doesn’t involve any auto-boxing. But if your assumption is to have a `List<Integer>` beforehand, that might not be an option, so if you are just interested in the `max` value, `Collections.max` might be the simpler choice.

But this would lead to the question why you have a `List<Integer>` beforehand. Maybe, it’s the result of old code (or new code written using old thinking), which had no other choice than using boxing and `Collection`s as there was no alternative in the past?

So maybe you should think about the source producing the collection, before bother with how to consume it (or well, think about both at the same time).

If all you have is a `Collection` and all you need is a single terminal operation for which a simple `Collection` based implementation exists, you may use it directly without bother with the `Stream` API. The API designers acknowledged this idea as they added methods like `forEach(…)` to the `Collection` API instead of insisting of everyone using `stream().forEach(…)`. And `Collection.forEach(…)` is not a simple short-hand for `Collection.stream().forEach(…)`, in fact, it’s already defined on the more abstract `Iterable` interface which even hasn’t a `stream()` method.

Btw., you should understand the difference between `Collections.binarySearch` and `Stream.filter/findAny`. The former requires the collection to be *sorted* and if that prerequisite is met, might be the better choice. But if the collection isn’t sorted, a simple linear search is more efficient than sorting just for a single use of binary search, not to speak of the fact, that binary search works with `List`s only while filter/findAny works with any stream supporting every kind of source collection.

Comment: Are you proposing that any new code that I write henceforth should not use a a `List` or a `Collection` but always use a `Stream`?

Comment: It’s not always that easy. That’s what I tried to explain. If your operation incorporates primitive data types and the operation can be expressed as a stream operation without any boxing, that’s preferable. If your operation consists of multiple steps or a combination of functions, the stream API is likely the way to go. If your data source is an existing collection or array and the intended operation can be expressed as a single invocation of an existing (collection-based) method, use that method. If you want to modify the collection in-place, stay at the collection API.